# How can I generate occlusion effects in meshes

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes, volumetrics, boolean-modifier

I have meshes representing complicated fields of views of observers (positioned at local origin of the mesh). I would like to calculate new meshes that take into account occlusions inside the fields of view meshes.

I have implemented something that kind of works using a combination of constraints and boolean modifiers:

[image: image of current solution]

this solution scales badly to more complicated geometries, is buggy (inherited from the boolean modifier).

Is there a way to do this in a better way? in particular, I am thinking of geometry nodes and mesh-to-volumetric based logic.

Comment: Hello. Iv'e explored something like that some time ago. You can read about it there https://wiki.osarch.org/index.php?title=Visualize_a_Line_of_Sight_in_Blender it's a technique used in video games to draw line of sight effects. It has its limitations but it should be pretty fast to generate. Would it be a good solution for you ?

Comment: @Gorgious .. wish I could UV that! Nice presentation.

Comment: @Gorgious. At first glance, it looks perfect! Thanks. Feel free to put up an answer.

Comment: have looked at the solution by @Gorgious in more detail. Its pretty straightforward, but its accuracy is tied to number of vertices used in the FOV mesh. My current solution does not have this drawback. Shouldnt there be a solution where mesh edges on the occluders can be cast towards the view point? this could be the basis of an accurate solution, not dependent on the resolution of the FOV mesh?

Comment: how about something like: 1) uniformly scale up all occluders around their centre of mass by 0.1% per unit distance to centre of view .2) project all the visible vertices of all the occluders to a low res ico sphere. 3) scale back the occluders to original size 4) remesh the sphere, so that those points are part of the mesh with same connectivity as on their original object (thus projecting the geometrical edges) 5) apply the geometry node that @Gorgious posted (but with this dynamic, ad hoc remeshed sphere).  Would that provide full accuracy, but with low-poly mesh?

Comment: as a first step, will add a simple subdivision modifier to my low polys, and then remove redundant vertices after. This will likely give pretty high accuracy as a good stand-in solution.